# Code AUTO DRAG When Enter Textbox In Vba Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

Please help, how to auto drag a value when hit/enter textbox in vba excel? Thanks before
or any textbox properties should i use my code?
like :
when i drop my crusor in the textbox, anyting value on textbox auto drag or block